# Can't figure out encoding or hash type

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, decode

I using an api that returns a bunch of strings like this one. I'm trying to figure out what type of hash or encoding they are:

```
\u0e23\u0e31\u0e1a\u0e04\u0e27\u0e32\u0e21\u0e17\u0e49\u0e32\u0e17\u0e32\u0e22\u0e14\u0e49\u0e32\u0e19\u0e20\u0e32\u0e1e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just unicode representation for this: รับความท้าทายด้านภาพ

Which is properly **Thai** -  that according to google translate, translates to:
***Get a visual challenge***